# Как запустить py скрипт без команды python в ZSH?

Tags: python, linux, bash, zsh

Пытаюсь понять как запустить скрипт из под виртуального окружения без его активации. Делаю так:

1. Добавил для файла права на исполнение:

```
sudo chmod +x myscript.py
```

Права на файл теперь выглядят так: `-rwxrwxr-x`

2. Добавил в скрипт shebang в первой строчке:

```
#!/home/path/venv/bin/python3
```

3. Перезапустил терминал.

Использую ZSH. При попытке запустить скрипт получаю ошибку:

> zsh: command not found: sitemap.py

Comment: можно через pyinstaller создать запускаемый файл

Comment: А так `./myscript.py`?

Comment: @Andrey а в вашем варианте пишет "отказано в доступе", хотя владелец файла я

Comment: @Andrey а, нет, это была моя опечатка в shebang. Все работает. А не могли бы объяснить почему не работает без `./`? Ну и можете как ответ оформить, отмечу как решение.

Comment: Юниксы не ищут команду в текущем каталоге. Это мера безопасности.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Когда вы пытаетесь запустить скрипт командой `myscript.py`, то система ищет такую команду в `PATH`. И если вы не добавили в `PATH` путь до каталога с вашим скриптом, то получите `command not found`. Поэтому, чтобы запустить скрипт из текущего каталога, нужно указывать `./` перед именем скрипта.
С запуском скрипта не из текущего каталога проблем не будет - просто введите путь до скрипта:

```
scripts_folder/myscript.py
```

Если очень нужно, то можете добавить ваш каталог со скриптом в `PATH`:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/path/to/script
```

Посмотреть содержимое `PATH` можно так:

```
echo $PATH
```

После этого сможете откуда угодно запускать ваш скрипт просто написав `myscript.py`

Comment: Я бы не менял PATH, даже если очень нужно. Лучше положить в /usr/local/bin или в ~/bin какой-нибудь враппер, в котором уже и прописывать путь до основного скрипта по необходиомсти.

Comment: @AlexanderProkoshev я вообще просто алиас написал в .zshrc, чтобы запускать скрипт кастомной командой

Comment: @КонстантинКомиссаров вполне нормальный вариант. Только привязанный к конкретному юзеру и конкретному шеллу этого юзыря.

Comment: @AlexanderProkoshev ну кроме меня никто эту команду запускать не будет, так что норм)

Comment: @КонстантинКомиссаров это все так всегда говорят, а потом персональные данные 60 млн. банковских карт уплывают :)